# Contents of std::vector Disappears in a std::unordered_map with Custom Key std::tuple<int*, int*>

Tags: c++, unordered-map

My program needs a hash map, its input is a range defined by two 3D coordinates (`int start[3]`, `int stop[3]`), and its output is a dynamic array of integers, defined as `std::vector<int>`. To implement this hash table, I declared `std::tuple<int*, int*>` to be a custom type called `CoordsKey`. Then I reimplemented `operator()` to calculate the hash value based on `start[3]` and `stop[3]` (for quick prototyping, I simply create a `std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int>` based on the values of `int *start` and `int *stop` so it's hashable by Boost).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp>

using CoordsKey = std::tuple<int*, int*>;

struct CoordsKeyHash {
        std::size_t operator()(const CoordsKey& key) const
        {
                /* std::tuple is hashable by Boost */
                std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int> t = { 
                        std::get<0>(key)[0], std::get<0>(key)[1], std::get<0>(key)[2],
                        std::get<1>(key)[0], std::get<1>(key)[1], std::get<1>(key)[2]
                };
                auto hash = boost::hash_value(t);

                fprintf(stderr, "access (%d, %d, %d)-(%d, %d, %d) with hash %ld\n",
                        std::get<0>(key)[0], std::get<0>(key)[1], std::get<0>(key)[2],
                        std::get<1>(key)[0], std::get<1>(key)[1], std::get<1>(key)[2],
                        hash
                );
                return hash;
        }
};

using CoordsMap = std::unordered_map<CoordsKey, std::vector<int>, CoordsKeyHash>;
```

Then this hash map can be accessed using the following code:

```
int start[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int end[3]   = {4, 5, 6};
auto& vec = map[std::make_tuple(start, end)];
```

Unfortunately, I found modifying the vectors inside this hash map has no effect, its contents disappears after returning from a function, as seen in the following demo:

```
#include "CoordsMap.h"

CoordsMap map;

void test(void)
{
        int start[3] = {1, 2, 3}; 
        int end[3]   = {4, 5, 6}; 

        map[std::make_tuple(start, end)] = std::vector<int>();
        map[std::make_tuple(start, end)].push_back(8);
        map[std::make_tuple(start, end)].push_back(9);
        fprintf(stderr, "vec size %ld\n",
                map[std::make_tuple(start, end)].size()
        );
}

int main(void)
{
        int start[3] = {1, 2, 3}; 
        int end[3]   = {4, 5, 6}; 

        test();

        auto& vec = map[std::make_tuple(start, end)];
        fprintf(stderr, "main(): vec size %ld\n", vec.size());
        for (auto& i : vec) {
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
}
```

After running this program, the output is:

```
access (1, 2, 3)-(4, 5, 6) with hash 3332428396118021859
access (1, 2, 3)-(4, 5, 6) with hash 3332428396118021859
access (1, 2, 3)-(4, 5, 6) with hash 3332428396118021859
access (1, 2, 3)-(4, 5, 6) with hash 3332428396118021859
vec size 2
access (1, 2, 3)-(4, 5, 6) with hash 3332428396118021859
main(): vec size 0
```

As one can see, after returning from `test()`, the modified contents inside the vector has disappeared, even though the exact same hash value is used to access its content.  I'm not sure what's going on here, but the symptom looks similar to what would happen when one attempts to use nonexistent local variable on the stack.

Curiously, the same problem doesn't occur if a simple `int` is used as the key:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>

using IntegerMap = std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>;
IntegerMap map;

void test(void)
{
        map[42].push_back(8);
        map[42].push_back(9);
        fprintf(stderr, "vec size %ld\n",
                map[42].size()
        );
}

int main(void)
{
        test();

        auto& vec = map[42];
        fprintf(stderr, "main(): vec size %ld\n", vec.size());
        for (auto& i : vec) {
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
}
```

The output of the second program is:

```
vec size 2
main(): vec size 2
8
9
```

### Question

The second program works, but the first does not, why? What is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::tuple<int*, int*>;
```

Although you've provided an appropriate hash function, for the unordered container, the default equality comparison function will still be the default one. Which means, effectively, the pointers themselves will be compared.

This is probably not going to do what you think it does. Two different pointers, that point to the same `int` values will not compare as equal, because they will be different. It's unlikely that this is going to be your expected result.

But that's the least of your troubles.

For both the hash function, and the equality comparison function (however it gets implemented), it obviously means that these pointers ***must remain valid***.

```
void test(void)
{
        int start[3] = {1, 2, 3}; 
        int end[3]   = {4, 5, 6};
```

This appears to be the `int` values that will form one of your keys.

These two objects, `start` and `end` will go out of scope and get destroyed when `test()` returns.

But they will be used as the underlying pointers in the unordered map.

Therefore, after `test()` returns, using the `unordered_map` will the become undefined behavior. These `int` values will no longer exist. The underlying pointers, in the map's key will point to destroyed objects.

There's a name for the underlying problem that's causing all of these troubles, it's called "Pointless Use Of Pointers". Replacing the container's key with, probably, a `std::tuple<std::vector<int>,std::vector<int>>` will likely solve all of the issues.

Comment: I see. The mistake here is that I forgot to provide a custom equality comparison.

Comment: Even after you provide one, as long as `test()` remains as it is you'll still be up the creek without a paddle, as explained.

Comment: In other words, does it mean that `unordered_map` always holds an internal copy of the key during its lifetime (e.g. to check for hash collisions)?

Comment: Yes. And the key is, effectively, a pair of `int *`, because that's what the key is. And ***only*** the pointers. Not anything that the pointers point to.